# Calculate difference between multiple rows in one query

Tags: sql

I have a table which has a numerical value in Account 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on, and a date (eg: today and yesterday)
How do I calculate the difference between Account 1, 2, 3, 4  from today and yesterday?
Thanks!

This is the data

```
+--------------+-------------+------------+
|      GL      |   Amount    |    Date    |
+--------------+-------------+------------+
| Bank account |    77000000 | 10/05/2019 |
| Bank account |    30373448 | 9/05/2019  |
| Cost         |    49552128 | 10/05/2019 |
| Cost         |  3363508.25 | 9/05/2019  |
| Div          |        3050 | 10/05/2019 |
| Div          | 609177.8125 | 9/05/2019  |
+--------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Proper columns would make your sample data easier to read. And specify the expected result as well.

Comment: What's the type of the 'Date' column? Is it a date or a varchar?

Comment: What DB are you using (Oracle, MySql)?

Comment: Your sample data has names for accounts, not  numbers, making the question very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
select y.account_value as yesterdays_value
    , b.account_value as todays_value
    , b.account_value - y.account_value as dif_in_account_value
from (select * from your_table where date_time = yesterday) y
join (select * from your_table where date_time = today) t
    on y.account_id = t.account_id
```

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, I have added the data layout above

Comment: Man that is an ugly table.  I'm sorry you have to work with that.  The [GL] column is a horrible way to store data.

Comment: Where is the account ID?  Your table data doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry 'GL' is the account. Need to calculate the diff between each Gl entry (Bank account, Cost, Div) between the two days

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you're using Oracle and that your 'Date' column is a `DATE` with a time always equal to 00:00:00, you might try the following:

```
SELECT tday.gl                   AS account,
       tday.amount               AS todays_amount,
       yday.amount               AS yesterdays_amount,
       tday.amount - yday.amount AS difference
FROM   my_table tday
JOIN   my_table yday
  ON   tday.gl = yday.gl
 AND   tday.date = yday.date + 1
WHERE  tday.date = TO_DATE('20190510', 'YYYYMMDD');
```

Of course, this returns a correct result only if for each account there's exactly 1 record for today and exactly 1 record for yesterday.